# How to bypass the keycloak login page?

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am working on a ReactJS application with a Java background. Is it possible to use a login other than that of keycloak.

I know it's possible to custom the default keycloak theme and add custom field also but I really want to use my reactjs login form instead of redirecting to that of keycloak.

Is it possible ?
Is it recommended ?

There is already a similar [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356300/avoid-keycloak-default-login-page-and-use-project-login-page) but not the right answer to the problem.

Thank you all for answering my question

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible ?

Yes, the user would insert the `username` and `password` into your form. And you would perform *behind the curtains* a call to a `Keycloak` `Client` that you would have to configure with the "*Resource Owner Password Credential Grant*" flow (*i.e.,* *Direct access Grants Enabled in Keycloak*). That *call* would be requesting a token on the user's behalf.

Now the problem with this approach is that *Resource Owner Password Credential Grant* should *typically* be avoided ([source](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html)):

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in
> cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the
> client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application. **The authorization server should take special care when
> enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not
> viable**.

You can read more on why it is not recommended to use that flow in sources such as [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications).

So you would be compromising a bite of security there. Moreover, you might want to provide other Keycloak functionality (*e.g.,* `OTP` and social media login) that is seamlessly integrated with its Theme template. Then you might have to adapt your application based on new Keycloak releases and so on. Unless you really have a very good reason to I would not recommend it. You can opt to simply customize the default theme. It is just a form anyway, after that the user can be immediately redirected to your app.

Comment: dreamcrash is absolutely right, but i want also add that with Resource Owner Password Credential Grant, you will also get a lot of pain with resolving tasks like token pair refreshing, handling SSO logout and other stuff